DS1343 SPI chip select logic in Linux driver
I am confused by this code in "drivers/rtc/rtc-ds1343.c" ds1343_probe for Linux kernel versions v5.6 to latest v6.10-rc4:
    /* RTC DS1347 works in spi mode 3 and
     * its chip select is active high. Active high should be defined as
     * "inverse polarity" as GPIO-based chip selects can be logically
     * active high but inverted by the GPIO library.
     */
    spi->mode |= SPI_MODE_3;
    spi->mode ^= SPI_CS_HIGH;
    spi->bits_per_word = 8;
    res = spi_setup(spi);
    if (res)
        return res;

If the device node has correctly used the spi-cs-high property (together with an ACTIVE_HIGH GPIO line if using GPIO for CS), then surely the statement spi->mode ^= SPI_CS_HIGH; will break it.
Prior to commit 3b52093dc917, the code in question was:
    /* RTC DS1347 works in spi mode 3 and
     * its chip select is active high
     */
    spi->mode = SPI_MODE_3 | SPI_CS_HIGH;
    spi->bits_per_word = 8;
    res = spi_setup(spi);
    if (res)
        return res;

which had the unfortunate effect of clobbering the existing SPI mode set-up completely.
The commit description contains:
The current use of mode flags to us SPI_MODE_3 and
SPI_CS_HIGH is fragile: it overwrites anything already
assigned by the SPI core. Change it thusly:

- Just |= the SPI_MODE_3 so we keep other flags
- Assign ^= SPI_CS_HIGH since we might be active high
  already, and that is usually the case with GPIOs used
  for chip select, even if they are in practice active low.

Add a comment clarifying why ^= SPI_CS_HIGH is the right
choice here.

My question: Is ^= SPI_CS_HIGH really the correct choice here, or would |= SPI_CS_HIGH be better?

It’s a long story and you should ask Linus Walleij about this. The answer is in the drivers/spi/spi.c and drivers/gpio/gpiolib-of.c.

@0andriy He was Cc'ed in my patch. I haven't had any replies yet.
